# Selection of data of the big table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big table with customers, `t_customer` that has 10.000.000 records.

I start a certain PHP script which chooses data from this table and I need to execute an action on each customer.

But as I progress through the data, the SQL inquiry runs more and more slowly, and now terminates with `Query execution was interrupted`.

My query is:

```
SELECT id, login FROM t_customer WHERE regdate<1370955715 LIMIT 2600000, 100000;
```

So the limit doesn't have any effect any more and I don't know what to do about this.

**P.S.**
    SELECT id, login FROM t_customer WHERE regdate<1370955715 LIMIT 2600000, 10;

the above query is executed 30 seconds

**P.S.S.**
The same result even without a WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are selecting 100K records in PHP? That is a bad idea.

**Lower your batch size to 1K**, paginate through your target set and then see how it goes. Make sure you have an index on the `regdate` too. 100K arrays in PHP are... complicated.

*PHP is a scripting language, it's not really C++ :) That's why I write background heavy-lifting workers in C++.*

Comment: +1: but rewriting this in C++ doesn't help with the problem. There are also issues around state management - using to transactions to handle this is not ideal.

Comment: The situation is so bad that even if you choose on the 1000 lines - "was interrupted". But at 10 - performed - 30 seconds ((

Comment: @frops Wow! Good thing I don't usually deal with such huge tables. I always find ways to split them.

Comment: If you are still having problems at 1000 lines, then definitely look at partitioning your table. Takes one or 2 commands to set up and you don't need to change any queries or anything. It's all done behind the scenes.

Comment: I second @ZorleQ but DO BACKUP first :)

Comment: It clearly looks like a database issue and not a PHP problem. Along with the above, make sure you are not running out of server resources while executing your queries, and if resources are fine, tweak your configuration a bit. Allow larger buffers, increase memory limits etc.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers a really clever feature called **partitions**. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

It allows you to automatically split huge data sets into smaller files giving you a huge improvement while doing operations on your data. Just like RAID but for SQL :P There was an excellent post on SO on the best configuration for partitions, but can't find it at the moment.

If you improve the performance of your query, PHP should instantly have more time to smash through your loops and arrays.